# I am having issue accessing the collection form FirebaseFirestore, Can any help me why I am getting the error?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to implement a login method but getting an error.
I might be doing some mistakes in referencing the collection, kindly help.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the brackets '()' after data. VS Code is telling you that data is a Function with the return type Map<String, dynamic>. You need to call that function in order to retrieve the actual Map.

Answer (score 0):

it seems like syntex mistack

You are missing the brackets '()' after data.